# Rust: tokio::io::copy vs io::copy

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to read and write to a stream that support tokio::AsyncRead + tokio::AsyncWrite.
The problem is my other stream only support io::Read + io::Write.
Basically I was hoping to do something like this

```rust
Let r, w = tokio::io::split(async_stream);
tokio::io::copy(pty_master, w);
tokio::io::copy(r, pty_master);
```

Problem is that pty_master only support std::io::Read and Write.

Comment: I hope it is not blocking, otherwise you should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `pty_master` implementations of `Read` and `Write` block then you'd block a tokio task thread by using them, which is not ideal.

One way to solve this would be to wrap `pty_master` in a type that implements `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` by using [`spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) under the hood.  The code to do this is rather complicated and probably out of the scope of an answer on this site.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of that as an option but it’s good to know before hand that it’s complex. Not to be presumptuous but it seems like you might have some insight into the more general task I am trying to accomplish. If you have free time could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629825/writing-an-ssh-daemon-in-rust

Comment: @michael_fortunato That is a very broad question and is likely to be closed as it's not focused enough. I threw together a [sample implementation of `AsyncRead` on top of `Read`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66a167bd055fcf71701e237257f59f92) -- note that it's untested and likely inefficient in some ways. An implementation of `AsyncWrite` would be similarly complicated.

Comment: Yes I can see that being the case. I think the core part of my ssh question is how best to wire input and output from the connection to child process's (command line app line bash) input and output.

Comment: @michael_fortunato I wrote the implementation of `AsyncWrite` as well just for the exercise. [Both implementations are here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=698030aa932aa5f113dc97fd1c5914c0). You are welcome to use the code, but just a reminder that I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in, but you can write your own:

```rust
use std::io::{ErrorKind, Read, Result};

use tokio::io::{AsyncWrite, AsyncWriteExt};

// https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/std/src/sys_common/io.rs#L3C92-L3C92
const DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE: usize = 8 * 1024;

pub async fn copy_half_async<R, W>(reader: &mut R, writer: &mut W) -> Result<u64>
where
    R: ?Sized + Read,
    W: ?Sized + AsyncWrite + Unpin,
{
    let mut buf = vec![0; DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE].into_boxed_slice();
    let mut len = 0;
    loop {
        let n = match reader.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(n) if n == 0 => break,
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        };

        len += n as u64;

        writer.write_all(&buf[..n]).await?;
    }

    Ok(len)
}
```

**Warning:** You should only use that if your reader is not blocking.

Comment: When you call `reader.read(..)`, you're blocking whole tokio thread.

Comment: @Dmitry Assuming the reader is blocking. This is not always true.

Comment: @Dmitry I added a warning.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful for me to see. If you have time could I get your insight on this more general question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629825/writing-an-ssh-daemon-in-rust